# Alternatives to eval

Tags: javascript, node.js, eval

My program processes many different types of documents to extract information from them. 
It has a very generic structure to fit the hundreds of different types/formats of docs we use.

**Processor Code :**

```
Processor.prototype.process = function(){
    var self = this;
    var fields = self.processor_config;
    var p = {};
    for(key in fields){
        if(fields.hasOwnProperty(key)){
            p[key]=self._processKey(fields[key]);
            if(typeof(p[key])=='undefined' || p[key]===''){
                self.emit('warning', {
                    type: 'Problem parsing Key',
                    msg: 'Key : '+key,
                    doc: self.docName
                });
            }
        }
    }
    self.emit('extracted',p);
};
```

The processKey() function then sorts out what to do based on the "type" field :

```
Productor.prototype._processKey = function(cnf) {
    var self = this;
    var value;
    if(cnf.type=="css"){
        value = self._processCSSKey(cnf);
    }else if(cnf.type=="regexp"){
        value = self._processRegexpKey(cnf);
    }else if(cnf.type=="custom"){
        value = self._processCustomKey(cnf);
    }
    return value;
};
```

Information on what to extract from each type of document comes from a mongodb collection :

**Fictional config with 2 types of fields :**

```
doc_name: "FormK7",
processor_config: {
    company:{
        type:"css"
        selector:"p",
        ord:3,
        attr:{type:"text",parser:""}
    },
    litigation:{
        type:"custom"
        func:"(function(){var a =['123'];return a})()"
    },
}
```

The example above is pretty useless, but the real thing has more complicated functions (not much though).

My custom processor looks like :

```
Productor.prototype._processCustomKey = function(cnf) {
    var value = eval(cnf.func);
    return value;
};
```

My problem is that I haven't found a way to process custom keys without using eval. And yet the simple mention of 'eval' brings to my mind pictures of an angry Douglas Crockford banishing me to a dark oblivion for all eternity...

**Additional info :**

- In real life, the function stored in mongo is minified.
- The generic processor is needed as having one processor per document type would be extremely wasteful (formats change all the time, there's hundreds of them and some are used once only...). So these functions need to be recorded in some way. And they are too different to be hardcoded...
- There is no user input and the app is not accessible from the web. A malicious user would have access to the server before being able to inject code in mongo, so the security concern is extremely low.

So the question is the following :

**Is eval really evil in this case, or is it a valid use case?** Is there a better way/best practice to handle this?

Comment: It's not clear where you'd use `eval` here in the first place. Generally the reason to avoid it is to run *arbitrary user data*, which is extremely dangerous. If you are constructing and sanitizing what goes into it, it's not entirely crazy, but you must be **extremely** careful which is why it's usually a tool of last resort.

Comment: I use eval in the 'processCustomKey' function. And I do agree that it's last resort, but I can't find an alternative out of the top of my head. the input is sanitized and the config isn't anywhere near anything a user could see. That particular component is buried deep into the back of the backend ;)

Comment: Perhaps would be better if you provide a more complicated example of function. In this example you could just have a property with value `[1,2,3]`, but of course is just an example to prove your point.

Comment: And I guess you can't just store a plain function expression in your config, right?

Comment: It could be a Date manipulation, or pretty much anything smallish, the point is that there's hundreds of possible variations on what the custom function may do.

Comment: actually, mongodb allows me to store a function expression (stringified I think). But how do I execute it in my code?

Comment: But why? What documents does your db store, what do data do they contain? Who creates those functions, and what exactly are they *used* for (I'm not interested in what they're doing, but where they're called). Please explain the purpose of your application.

Comment: The code basically creates datasets out of many different company docs, some in html, some in txt, csv, etc. The functions are created by the guys in charge to convert those docs into data we'll use in another component. Think of it as a very hopeful harmonization operation between many different components. Something that up until now was done by a guy and a notepad, reading through each doc to find the relevant info, then inputting it into the next piece of software

Comment: I think it's a valid use. You could create your own set of predefined functions and limit users to calling those with certain parameters, but you might need quite a few. As long as you're aware that you're running arbitrary code and take suitable precautions (like making user it's well documented and run in a sandboxed environment), I don't see an issue. Would malicious code have access to anything useful anyway?

Comment: @RobG they could troll the output at most... And to do that they would have to have compromized the server already, so I don't really see the point :)

Comment: Hm, "those guys in charge" are only users as well, and could possibly develop malicious intentions (oh, and of course it's not hard to write a DOS procedure by accident). Why are you executing those functions over and over, instead of converting the data only once into the standard format (best done client-side at the person who uploads the data)?

Comment: @Bergi Some of those docs are changed on a daily/weekly basis... I am making sure at this point that every input is sanitized so the only weak link in there are the devs who create the config objects, which I personally review before adding them to the db I'm in charge of... There's no 'client side' to this app really.

Comment: I would use a git repo instead of using mongo. But anyway,  perhaps you could dump the function to a temporal file, and then use nodejs' `require`. That way you wont be evaling.

Comment: @Bergi and I'd love to have everything standardized but... like everywhere else, it'd mean for the company to spend a lot of money getting rid of a lot of outdated software

Comment: @chris-l That sounds like it could work actually, I could even generate JS files from mongo, and use require. I need to think that through, if you want to make it in an answer, that sounds very relevant. Thanks!

Comment: @xShirase: That the docs change often doesn't sound as if the conversion functions would do as well. I'd believe that they should not *change* at all, only new ones might get added. And it doesn't sound they are dynamic enough to require being stored in a DB, "hardcoding" (as you call it) them in the source should be enough. Or is it a distributed application that doesn't get released often with a complicated update procedure?

Comment: @chris-l: `require`ing a file isn't much different from `eval` except maybe for the scope, but the `Function` constructor should be able to do that as well.

Comment: @Bergi, to put it simply, it's a massive mess, and I cannot rely on anyone but me to find a path through it... Technically, I could do it all manually as long as they don't hear about it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a module that exports from mongo to a temporal file and then use `require` to import that file. That way you wont be evaling and, like Bergi mentioned, it would prevent the scope problems that `eval` has.

Also, once you export it, and before requiring it, you could use something like Esprima to create an AST of the code and analyse it to see if it complies with some criteria you may have. (Like, perhaps, you could forbid the use of `this` in the code imported as a safety measure - thats part of the rules ADSafe has)